# convert date/time to hours in quickbase

Tags: datetime, quickbase

Example: created a record on date 07/19/2016, 10:00AM, I wanted it to be converted into hours(timestamp) and display as 54 hours in quickbase. Appreciate your help

Comment: If possible, please provide more detailed information on the problem you're having.  It's not clear what you're trying to accomplish exactly and whether you're trying to do it in a formula field within Quickbase or through a programming language like JavaScript.

Comment: I am trying to convert the date/time field into hours field in quickbase

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert a timestamp into the hours in a formula field you can do it with the `ToTimeOfDay()` and `Hours()` functions.  Say you want to display the hour only of the Date Created field you can put this formula into a formula-numeric field:

```
Hour(ToTimeOfDay([Date Created]))
```

If you need to use a formula - duration field for some reason, just put all of the above through the `Hours()` function:

```
Hours(Hour(ToTimeOfDay([Date Created])))
```

Comment: I tried using the above formula, but was not receiving the acurate result

Comment: If possible, please include more detail about how the result is not accurate.  Also, consider providing more detail in your original question.  It's difficult to answer a question where most of the details are left to the answer's imagination.